# Issue 'Modal Dialog Present' happening after latest update with Internet Explorer 11 (KB4021558)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am getting 'Modal dialog present' exception while running my test cases which was working fine till 23rd July. On 24th July, Microsoft rolled out an update KB4021558 regarding some vulnerability fix for IE 11. After this update, I am getting an exception while executing an AutoIT exe for handling a Windows-based pop-up.

Please see the configurations below.

OS : Windows 10
IE Driver : 3.13.0 (32 Bit)
IE Version : IE 11.0.10240.17443 (KB4021558)

Is anyone having same issues with the latest IE update?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to overcome this issue. As selenium is now detecting the Windows Security Popup as an alert, I am using alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password") method (I am using Selenium Webdriver 3.13 with C#) to fix the issue. Previously selenium was unable to detect this window as an alert.